# What's the significance of leap years in Poe's “The Thousand-and-Second Tale of Scheherazade”?

Tags: short-stories, edgar-allan-poe

[Edgar Allan Poe's story “The Thousand-and-Second Tale of Scheherazade” (link to full text)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Works_of_the_Late_Edgar_Allan_Poe/Volume_1/The_Thousand-and-Second_Tale_of_Scheherazade) has this curious sentence.  This is about Scheherazade volunteering to marry the king, despite knowing that the king would kill her on the morning after the wedding.

> Accordingly, and although we do not find it to be leap-year, (which makes the sacrifice more meritorious,) she deputes her father, the grand vizier, to make an offer to the king of her hand.

I don't understand how leap years are relevant at all.  What is the significance of leap years?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, the American practice was that a man asked a woman to marry him, not for the woman to ask the man.  For a woman to ask was very forward and unfeminine of her.

There was a practice imported from [Ireland](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/leap-day-february-29.html) that women could ask men to marry them in a leap year.

Scheherazade is not only asking the king to marry her, she is doing it when it might be regarded as a flaw in her character.

Comment: [Better link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor%27s_Day_(tradition)). I knew about this tradition, but didn't know it originated in Ireland - interesting!